# Advanced find and replace. Where do begin?

Tags: replace, find

I have an HTML page that has over 1500 of these links. The a href is wrong. How can I replace "images/image01.jpg" in this example with "fullsize/IMG_0028.JPG" repeatedly throughout the document. (the correct file name will always be in the same location).

```
<a href="images/image01.jpg">
 IMG_0028.JPG
</a>
```

Comment: doesn't your editor have a find and replace function? usually ctrl+F will activate it.

Comment: regular expression search and replace with a capturing group. Most editors have that functionality these days, but without knowing your OS / editor, I can't give you a specific suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a free editor like Notepad++ (http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) or Sublime (http://www.sublimetext.com/). Then click Ctrl+F or Ctrl+H (or simmilar) and choose the string to replace.